# Why is my Doc2Vec model in gensim not reproducible?

Tags: gensim, word2vec, random-seed, doc2vec

I have noticed that my gensim Doc2Vec (DBOW) model is sensitive to document tags. My understanding was that these tags are cosmetic and so they should not influence the learned embeddings. Am I misunderstanding something? Here is a minimal example:

```py
from gensim.test.utils import common_texts
from gensim.models.doc2vec import Doc2Vec, TaggedDocument
import numpy as np
import os
    
os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED'] = '0'
    
reps = []
for a in [0,500]:
    documents = [TaggedDocument(doc, [i + a]) 
                 for i, doc in enumerate(common_texts)]
    model = Doc2Vec(documents, vector_size=100, window=2, min_count=0,
                    workers=1, epochs=10, dm=0, seed=0)
    reps.append(np.array([model.docvecs[k] for k in range(len(common_texts))])
    
reps[0].sum() == reps[1].sum()
```

This last line returns `False`. I am working with gensim 3.8.3 and Python 3.5.2. More generally, is there *any* role that the values of the tags play (assuming they are unique)? I ask because I have found that using different tags for documents in a classification task leads to widely varying performance.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked the magnitude of the differences?

Just running:

```
delta = reps[0].sum() - reps[1].sum()
```

for the aggregate differences results with `-1.2598932e-05` when I run it.

Comparison dimension-wise:

```
 eps = 10**-4
 over = (np.abs(diff) <= eps).all()
```

Returns `True` on a vast majority of the runs which means that you are getting quite reproducible results given the complexity of the calculations.

I would blame [numerical stability](https://nhigham.com/2020/08/04/what-is-numerical-stability/#:%7E:text=Numerical%20stability%20concerns%20how%20errors,can%20be%20from%20any%20source.) of the calculations or uncontrolled randomness. Even though you do try to control the random seed, there is a different random seed in NumPy and different in `random` standard library so you are not controlling for all of the sources of randomness. This can also have an influence on the results but I did not check the actual implementation in `gensim` and it's dependencies.

Comment: Yes, you're right: it's just small noise from other sources. Your answer actually also pointed me in the right direction for finding the true source of the (large) difference between seeds in my application.

Comment: It's **not** numerical calculation jitter. It's probably not even uncontrolled randomness – given the reduction to a single worker & constant seed, which may be able to force determinism within a single Python launch (even though doing so is usually a bad idea with this algorithm). See sibling answer for deeper problems with this test.

Answer (score 2):

First & foremost, your test isn't even comparing vectors corresponding to the same texts!

In run #1, the vector for the 1st text in in `model.docvecs[0]`. In run #2, the vector for the 1st text is in `model.docvecs[1]`.

And, in run #2, the vector at `model.docvecs[0]` is just a randomly-initialized, but never-trained, vector - because none of the training texts had a document `tag` of (int) `0`. (If using pure ints as the doc-tags, `Doc2Vec` uses them as literal indexes - potentially leaving any unused slots less than your highest tag allocated-and-initialized, but never-trained.)

Since `common_texts` only has 11 entries, by the time you reach run #12, *all* the vectors in your `reps` array of the first 11 vectors are garbage uncorrelated with any of your texts/

However, even after correcting that:

As explained in the [Gensim FAQ answer #11](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/wiki/Recipes-&-FAQ#q11-ive-trained-my-word2vec--doc2vec--etc-model-repeatedly-using-the-exact-same-text-corpus-but-the-vectors-are-different-each-time-is-there-a-bug-or-have-i-made-a-mistake-2vec-training-non-determinism), determinism in this algorithm shouldn't generally be expected, given many sources of potential randomness, and the fuzzy/approximate nature of the whole approach. If you're relying on it, or testing for it, you're probably making some unwarranted assumptions.

In general, tests of these algorithms should be evaluating "roughly equivalent usefulness in comparative uses" rather than "identical (or even similar) specific vectors". For example, a test whether `apple` and `orange` are roughly at the same positions in each others' nearest-neighbor rankings makes more sense than checking their (somewhat arbitrary) exact vector positions or even cosine-similarity.

Additionally:

- tiny toy datasets like `common_texts` won't show the algorithm's usual behavior/benefits
- `PYTHONHASHSEED` is only consulted by the Python interpreter at startup; setting it from Python can't have any effect. But also, the kind of indeterminism it introduces only comes up with separate interpreter launches: a tight loop within a single interpreter run like this wouldn't be affected by that in any case.

Comment: Thank you for the illuminating explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
import os
    
os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED'] = '0'
```

to

```
import os
import sys
hashseed = os.getenv('PYTHONHASHSEED')
if not hashseed:
    os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED'] = '0'
    os.execv(sys.executable, [sys.executable] + sys.argv)
```